# Why are my css table styles being mixed

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand what I have done wrong here. The css styles should be separate for both my tables however "rcorners1" table appears to be affected by the settings of "water_table"

I have two tables the css for first table

```
table.water_table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
table.water_table tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
table.water_table th {background-color: #ffffff;}
table.water_table th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

My first table looks like

```
<table border="0" align="center" class="water_table" id="water_table">
```

The css for my second table

```
    table.rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #a4b3bd;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 160px;
    float: left;
}
```

my second table looks like

```
<table width="100%" border="0"  class="rcorners1" id="rcorners1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the correct solution. What I did to correct the issue is to remove "water_table" from the css style file and created a style block within the html before my "water_table" appears.

```
<style>
table.water_table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
table.water_table tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5}
table.water_table th {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    /*color: white;*/
}
table.water_table th, td {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you don't want to put an inline style block inside your HTML - if you were to do so, it should be at the head of your document, not in the body.

However, if moving the styles is what solved the problem for you, this means that there's something else in your css file that's overriding your desired styles.

Often times you can see all of the styles associated with an element in a browser inspector. If you were to inspect your element I bet you would see some additional styles that are crossed out from your CSS file.